# Solving for Center Manifold with Parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

I have a system of ODEs given by

$$\frac{dX}{d\tau}=\beta X\left(1 - \frac{X+Y}{N}\right)$$

$$\frac{dY}{d\tau}= Y\left(1 - \frac{X+Y}{N}\right)$$

where $\beta $ is a parameter.

How should I approach this problem and find the center manifold and its stability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing a phase diagram would probably have shown you right away that  the nonnegative quadrant $Q=(X\geqslant0,Y\geqslant0)$ is stable by the dynamics, that the equilibria in the quadrant $Q$ are the point $(X,Y)=(0,0)$ and the segment $S=(X\geqslant0,Y\geqslant0,X+Y=N)$, and that $(0,0)$ is an unstable node. At every point $(X_0,Y_0)$ on $S$, an eigenvalue is $0$ (in the direction of $S$), the other one is real negative, and the center manifold is stable with equation $XY_0^\beta=Y^\beta X_0$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

$\qquad\qquad$`streamplot[{.3x(1-(x+y)),y(1-(x+y))},{x,0,2},{y,0,2}]`

Comment: Thanks @Did. I was wondering on an analytical approach because I'm working on a more complex version of this problem. Anyway, I am still not sure how did you get the equation of the center manifold $XY_o^\beta = XY_o$. Additionally, just to confirm, I plotted the phase portrait, and the center manifold is stable because the trajectories seem to flow towards it right? Heres the phase portrait I plotted: http://i61.tinypic.com/zx1cuc.jpg

Comment: Typo: $XY_0^\beta=Y^\beta X_0$.

Comment: Could I trouble you to explain / (or refer me to a link that explains) how you arrived at the equation of the center manifold?

Comment: Noet that $$(\log X)'=\frac1XX'=\beta\left(1-\frac{X+Y}N\right)=\beta\frac1YY'=(\log Y^\beta)'.$$